# Use normal keys as modifier keys, e.g. press S and F together instead of Ctrl+S to save file

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to use normal keys as modifier keys? Assuming my keyboard correctly records my pressing <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>F</kbd> together, is there a way for me to use the combination as a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>?

Specifically:

- How do I test that my keyboard is capable of detecting simultaneous keypresses?
- How can I remap the combination so that it can be used by an application like Emacs?

Comment: Autokey baby. . .

Comment: care to elaborate, honey?

Answer (score 3):

#### Q: How do I test that my keyboard is capable of detecting simultaneous keypresses?

**A:** You could use [KeyCodes](http://delphiforfun.org/programs/utilities/KeyCodes.htm) to monitor what Windows sees when pressing keyboard keys. In the picture below are three keys pressed simultaneously. `OnKeyDown` meens it's currently pressed and `OnKeyUp` triggers when you release the button.

[image]

---

#### Q: How can I remap the combination so that it can be used by an application like Emacs?

One possible way is to use AutoHotKey. I recommend the [portable version of AutoHotKey](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=217) to avoid the installation of additional software

The example shows how to remap key <kbd>A</kbd> to key <kbd>B</kbd>

```
A::SendInput {B}
```

It's also possible to add modifiers like <kbd>Win</kbd>(#), <kbd>Alt</kbd>(!), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>(^) or <kbd>Shift</kbd>(+). Read the AHK manual section [*HotKeys*](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) for more info

```
+!A::SendInput {B}
```

Our main problem is that AHK cannot bind more than one base key. Base keys are all keyboard keys except modifier keys.

Luckily there is a trick. We only use <kbd>S</kbd> to trigger a small macro where we next check if <kbd>F</kbd> is pressed. If yes, we send our new key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

```
~S::
  GetKeyState, state, F
  if state = D
  SendInput ^{s} 
Return

~F::
  GetKeyState, state, S
  if state = D
  SendInput ^{s} 
Return
```

- The downside is we have to do this for the other way around too where <kbd>F</kbd> is pressed first and then <kbd>S</kbd>
- Don't forget the tilde `~` in front of a key which means the native function should not be blocked
- Don't send an uppercase `^{S}` or else AHK will send an additional <kbd>Shift</kbd> keystroke. I have no clue why. However, a lowercase `^{s}` works as expected

---

Here is a AutoHotKey beginners [guide on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAiBHjCS9Qk#t=12) together with some useful links

- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands.htm
- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm
- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm
- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm